# Print first values of a matrix and find mean

Tags: r

I have this matrix named: nb.loop

```
nb.loop<-cbind(NB_evppi_Immediately_outer,NB_evppi_Watchfully_outer)
```

It has just two columns, and i need to find the mean of each column ( i know you can use he colMean function but don't know how to apply it)

Something like:

```
colMeans(nb.loop)
nb.loop <- 0:9
```

I use this code to ge the maximum of the columns:

```
baseline <- max(colMeans(nb.loop))
```

But i don't know how to apply it to get them separately.
And also, how can i print just the first 10 values of each column of the matrix?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`colMeans`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/colSums.html) returns a vector with the mean of each column, e.g. :

```
nb.loop <- matrix(1:4,nrow=2)

> nb.loop
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4

avgs <- colMeans(nb.loop)

> avgs 
[1] 1.5 3.5
```

To print just the first 10 rows of the matrix, you can use the function [`head`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/head.html), e.g.

```
nRowToPrint <- 10
print(head(nb.loop,nRowToPrint))
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, i print the avg and i get his error:
Error in base::colMeans(x, na.rm = na.rm, dims = dims, ...) : 
  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions

Comment: I notice that in your code you have this line `nb.loop <- 0:9` (i.e. you're replacing your matrix with a vector from 0 to 9). Have you called that line ? If so, maybe `nb.loop` is not a matrix any more... and colMeans works only on matrices...

Answer (score 0):

You can use apply() to exercise any function across the columns of your array.

```
> nb.loop <- matrix(1:12, ncol = 2)
> nb.loop
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    7
[2,]    2    8
[3,]    3    9
[4,]    4   10
[5,]    5   11
[6,]    6   12
```

For example, to find the means:

```
> apply(nb.loop, 2, mean)
[1] 3.5 9.5
```

To find the maxima (also mentioned in the original post):

```
> apply(nb.loop, 2, max)
[1]  6 12
```